# Incompatible pointer initializing NSMutableString with an expression of type NSString - Warning

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring

Hi guys i got this piece of code and got a warning "Incompatible pointer initializing NSMutableString with an expression of type NSString" and a mem leak. does anyone seem to know how to correct this?

```
- (IBAction)numberClicked:(id)sender {

    UIButton * numberBtn = (UIButton*)sender;

    NSMutableString *value = (self.textField.text == nil ? [NSMutableString new] : self.textField.text );
    [value appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberBtn.tag]];

    self.textField.text = value;
}
```

thnaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the incompatible pointer warning, you need to assign a mutable copy of `self.textField.text` to `value`:

```
NSMutableString *value = (self.textField.text == nil ? [NSMutableString new] : [self.textField.text mutableCopy] );
```